# Add port to 127.0.0.1

Tags: macos, couchdb, port, osx-mavericks

How can I add a port to `127.0.0.1`? I have `127.0.0.1:5984` open but want to open another one. Any idea? As A head's up I'm new to computers. I'm on a Mac running OS X Mavericks. I'm also on Xfinity.

Edit: I am having a port conflict while attempting to use CouchDB, how can I resolve this?

Comment: You might want to include some more information.  I think it might be different depending on things like which OS you use.  Or if this is on your router, include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A port is a listener for a specific protocol such as tcp or udp. In order to open a port. You need a program or service to listen on that port. For example, by default Skype will listen on port 80.

Please read the wikipedia page for a basic overview or what a port is.

> In computer networking, a port is an application-specific or
>   process-specific software construct serving as a communications
>   endpoint in a computer's host operating system. A port is associated
>   with an IP address of the host, as well as the type of protocol used
>   for communication.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Port

Edit: To answer actual question:

Unavailable Port

Problem

> $ couchdb       Apache CouchDB 0.9.0a747640 (LogLevel=info) is
>   starting. Failure to start Mochiweb: eaddrinuse {"init terminating in
>   do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,shutdown}},[{couch_server_sup,start_server,1},{erl_eval,do_apply,5},{erl_eval,exprs,5},{init,start_it,1},{init,start_em,1}]}}
>   Solution
>
> Edit your /etc/couchdb/couch.ini file and change the Port setting to
>   an available port.

Excerpt from:
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Error_messages

Comment: Here's my issue though. I am using couchDB which is on `127.0.0.1:5984` and another program is trying to use the same port. I want to somehow stop that conflict.

Comment: If this solves your problem don't forget to hit the green checkmark. For future reference, if you don't do your due diligence when writing a stack overflow question, you will receive down votes and less people will bother to read your question. Please google your issue thoroughly next time =).

Comment: Thank you for being super helpful so far. I'm new and want to learn as much as I can. What would an available port be? Can I change it to `127.0.0.1:5983`?

Comment: There is no registry for what programs use what port. Your best bet is usually trial and error. However you can list all ports in use: `sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"` from http://juretta.com/log/2007/08/08/list_open_ports_on_your_machine_mac_os_x_/

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks' for teaching me something today. :)

Comment: Don't forget to register an account here and accept this question as the anwser ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the port CouchDB listens on by editing its `local.ini` file (which is in `/usr/local/etc/couchdb` by default). Under the `httpd` section, uncomment the `port` entry and change its value to the port you want to listen on (5983 in your example).

Comment: I figured it out the fouton.